# Github - Making pull requests on a repository that I own

Tags: git, github, repository, pull-request, owner

I am new to Git and GitHub. I was wondering if I should be making pull requests on a repository that I own, or I should just commit my changes to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should. It is a good practice to use different feature branches while you develop a project. As you finish developing a feature, you pull the changes from that branch to another.

Answer (score 1):

[Pull requests](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-requests) are mostly about reviewing work with collaborators when adding code changes to a shared repository. If you're the only person working on a repository, then there's no need to open a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

- Only you work on the repository, use different branch to add features, bug fix and so on, and then merge to master when your jobs done. Keep master branch deployable.
- If you work on other's repository as a collaborator, use Pull Request and submit request to owner when you jobs done. If owner accept your request, your jobs will be merge to the repository.